# Polynomial matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is a nonzero constant.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As you can see in the title, I want to prove that a polynomial matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is a nonzero constant.

So far, I'm guessing that the proof would not be the same for the invertibility of a regular matrix.

This is what I have constructed so far...

(if) Suppose that the determinant of an n by n matrix $A$ is a nonzero constant. Then by the invertibility matrix theorem, $A$ is an invertible matrix.

(only if)
Suppose that an n by n polynomial matrix A is invertible. Then there exists an n by n polynomial matrix B such that 
$AB=I_n$. Then,

$det(AB) = det(A) * det(B) = det(I_n) = 1$.

If $det(A)$ is zero, then we end up with $0 = 1$ , which is a contradiction.

If $det(A)$ is a nonzero polynomial, then ...

...

This is where I'm stuck.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What do you mean, specifically, by a polynomial matrix? Are we looking at a matrix with polynomials for entries? If so, are the coefficients in $\Bbb{R}$, $\Bbb{C}$, or some other field? Are they single variable polynomials? Also, what do you mean by invertible? Do you mean that specifically another polynomial matrix must multiply to it give the identity constantly? Or can it just be a matrix whose entries are functions, but not necessarily polynomials?

Comment: What is a polynomial matrix? A matrix with coefficients in a polynomial ring? In that case you can use that the product of two polynomials is a constant iff they are both constant (if the underlying ring is an integral domain, e.g. a field)

Comment: My textbook calls it a λ-matrix, which I've discovered to be a polynomial matrix: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_matrix). @PrudiiArca , I will check that theorem out; I believe that's the way to continue. Thank you!

Comment: @JasperRaspberry What exactly is the "invertibility matrix theorem"?  You need the fact that if $\det(A)$ is a non-zero constant, then the *polynomial matrix* $A$ has an inverse.  If the "invertibility matrix theorem" only applies to matrices with constant entries, then this needs further justificaiton.

Comment: @JasperRaspberry Note that (assuming you're talking about polynomials with real/complex entries) Prudii's "theorem" just amounts to observing that the degree of the product of two polynomials is the sum of the degrees, which is easy enough to show directly.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Could you please elaborate on how I would go on to prove the (if) direction? It did seem a little incomplete to me as well, but I didn't know how to go on about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proof.

**If:** Suppose that $A(x)$ has a non-zero, constant derivative.  We note that
$$
A(x) \operatorname{adj}(A(x)) = \det(A(x)) I
$$
where adj denotes the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix).  Because $\det(A(x))$ is a non-zero constant, we can divide by it to get
$$
A(x) \cdot \frac{\operatorname{adj}(A(x))}{\det(A(x))} = I.
$$
We similarly find that $\frac{\operatorname{adj}(A(x))}{\det(A(x))} \cdot A(x) = I$, so that $\frac{\operatorname{adj}(A(x))}{\det(A(x))}$ is the inverse of $A(x)$.  So, $A(x)$ is indeed invertible.

**Only if:** Suppose that $A(x)$ is invertible.  That is, there exists a matrix polynomial $B(x)$ such that $A(x)B(x) = I$.  It follows that 
$$
\det(A(x)) \det(B(x)) = \det(I) = 1.
$$
We see that both $\det(A(x))$ and $\det(B(x))$ must be non-zero. For non-zero polynomials $p,q$, we have $\deg(pq) = \deg(p) + \deg(q)$.  Since $1$ is a degree-$0$ polynomial, both $\det(A(x)),\det(B(x))$ must be of degree $0$, which is to say that they are constant polynomials.  So, $\det(A(x))$ is indeed constant.